# Duplicating a React app folder does not work?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

(This is on a Mac by the way. It seems `cp -r` on a Mac is "historical" and should be replaced by `cp -R`).

I tried the following:

```
mkdir TryContext
cd TryContext
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

and then I made an app that worked, and `npm start` was able to start the server and run it.

But then if I want to make a version 2 of this app, and started by cloning the folder first:

```
cd ..
cp -r my-app my-app-02
```

to copy everything to `my-app-02`, and `cd` into that folder and do `npm start`, it will error, saying

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /Users/username/code/TryContext/my-app-02
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
```

I tried different ways, and tried `npm rebuild` and then `npm start`, and it worked. But I thought if you copy a directory "as is", then using it, `npm start` should start the server without needing to do anything?  Why was that and what ways besides `npm rebuild` could fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;RD:** when you copy using `cp -r` it doesn't really preserve symlinks, it just copies the file contents instead. So `npm start` can't find necessary symlink in this particular case. One of the possible solutions is to use `cp -a` when coping, which preserves symlinks and avoids this issue.

Mode detailed answer is [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/200#issuecomment-235233422)

:)

Comment: it is due to node_modules not wanting to duplicate files but use sym links? supposedly even sym link should work but it is not a good way because I don't want app2 linking to app1... but since I haven't renamed app1 yet, so theoretically it should still work.  In Ruby on Rails we usually copy the whole folder and it is good as the other

Comment: The issue is that symlinks aren't being copied with `cp -r`, that's why `npm start` can't find the file. If got a point of symlinks correct, they're just a reference to another file or folder. And in our case, most likely, symlinks don't point out at something in app1, but rather, they refer to something outside of that folder. So I do believe it's safe to delete app1 after copying it with `cp -a`, have you tried deleting it? just for the sake of testing :)

Comment: ah... "Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports
     that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy
     special files, symbolic links, or fifo's."

Comment: do you know if `-P` is not as proper as `-a`? `-a` won't "follow" symbolic link... does that mean possibly missing sym links if it is a folder?

Comment: I don't really know much about the difference between them, yet I found that if symlink is relative, it'll stay the same after copying with `-a`, which might not a desirable behavior